# stuck in a python 3 loop

Tags: python

I need to create a function that return the complementary sequence in a DNA sequence given. For example, if you call this function with 'AT' as the argument, it should return 'TA'. But i dont really know how to create it if a DNA sequence can have any length. If the complementary nucleotide are A=T G=C how can I develop a function that returns a complementary sequence.
Firstly I had the idea to create a loop in order to create it but I get stuck.

This is my initial code:

```
def get_complementary_sequence(sequence):
    """ (str) --> str
     Return the DNA sequence that is complementary to the given DNA sequence
     >>> get_complementary_sequence('AT')
     'TA'
     >>> get_complementary_sequence('GC')
     'CG'
     """

    for char in sequence:
        if char in 'ATCG':
            sequence = sequence + 1
```

Comment: Don't modify a value that you are iterating over

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that? It's a really dirty solution but does the trick

```
def get_complementary_sequence(sequence):
    mp = {"A":"T", 
          "T":"A",
          "C":"G", 
          "G":"C"}

    return ''.join(mp[c] for c in sequence)
```

Also note that this only works if the sequence only contains A, T, C or G.

Comment: Why do you consider this a "really dirty" solution? Looks very reasonable to me. (For memory efficiency, remove the square brackets so that you have a generator expression instead of a list comprehension: `''.join(mp[c] for c in sequence)`)

Comment: Extract `mp` out of the function, as it's a constant and you create same `dict` every time the function is called.

Comment: Thanks for the advie, @das-g. I often forget about that little detail...

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. You can configure `PAIRS` in human-friendly manner:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

PAIRS = [
    ('A', 'T'),
    ('G', 'C'),
]
COMPLEMENTATIONS = {
    k: v
    for k, v in
    chain(*chain(list(itertools.permutations(p)) for p in PAIRS))
}

def get_complementary_sequence(sequence):
    return ''.join(map(COMPLEMENTATIONS.get, sequence))
```

Usage:

```
get_complementary_sequence('ATGCCGTAATTTCGCA')
'TACGGCATTAAAGCGT'
```

Comment: That looks totally easier than mine